# Remove the OR operator but it still to give the same output

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

I have call for an written exam for Software Engineer. They give a queastion but i think i can not answer it properly. The queastion was

```
if(type == "string" || type == "int" || type ="char" || type == "double") 
return true;
else 
return false;
```

Remove the or operator but it still to give the same output.

Comment: Yeah, but we don't have that exam, do we? Or, if we solve it for you, will we get graded instead of you?

Comment: but i need to know it

Comment: Well, then improve your knowledge of boolean algebra. (I am sure you got plenty of study material) That's what this exam question is testing you for, after all. With boolean algebra, you can transform your boolean expression into an equivalent one not using OR, but using a combination of other boolean operators...

Comment: thanks @elgonzo i will try to learn it

Comment: read about (De Morgan's law), it will help you

Comment: Since i don't know the context of your exam, it could also be that instead of testing boolean algebra, this exam question is trying to test you about collection types in .NET. (Like the question might try to get you to replace that code there with some collection-based look-up logic) Anyway, the study materials you got should point you in the right direction...

Comment: @elgonzo this was a written exam test that i have already sited for. As it was uncommon tom me  so want to get knowledge of it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there not enough effort or research shown. "Just concert it" is not a question.

Comment: As a hint, use `Any()` extension method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using linq,

```
string[] primitiveTypes = new string[4] {"int", "double", "char", "string"};
string type = "double";
```

---

[Contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.8)

```
return primitiveTypes.Contains(type);
```

---

[Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8)

```
return primitiveTypes.Any(x => x == type);
```

---

[Array.Exists()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.exists?view=netframework-4.8)

```
return Array.Exists(primitiveTypes, x => x == type);
```

---

[Array.IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netframework-4.8)

```
return Array.IndexOf(primitiveTypes, type) > -1;
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I got your question rigth. If yes, then this is the correct answer:

`if(!(type != "string" && type != "int" && type != "char" && type != "double"))`

Comment: actually they do not to use any conditional operator ....they want a solution without conditional operator

Comment: @Sabbir, then **edit** and clarify your question and its title. As the question is presented and worded now, it strongly suggests you want/have to to keep the overall code and just want to change the boolean expression within the `if`. The answers here are related to your question. And based on the question asked, the answers are correct (as far as i can tell, but don't take my word for it)

Answer (score 1):

There is possibly a typo in there. Or maybe the question is designed to be a trick question. I see `...type == "int" || type ="char"...` and because the second part has a single equals sign you are going to get Operator '||' cannot be applied to types of bool and string.

Comment: This would be the most useless exam question ever. What would such a trick question really test? What would failing or passing such a trick question really indicate? Essentially nothing, aside from the fact that the person taking the exam just at that moment spotted an error in a source code snippet that doesn't seem to be related to the asked task (remove OR operator).  I am not arguing that there might not be such exam questions, but if there are exams using such trick questions, i question the validity and quality of such an exam...

Comment: @elgonzo I can't offer any explanation here. I noticed the anomaly and just didn't want to assume it being a typo.

Comment: No, don't worry. I understand you. I wasn't questioning you in my comment. I was rather questioning any (hypothetical) exam that would employ such kind of trick question... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a switch statement:

```
      switch (type.ToLower())
      {
            case "string":
            case "int":
            case "char":
            case "double":
                return true;
            default:
                return true;
      }
```

But you could use && like this:

```
if (!(type != "string" && type != "int" && type != "char" && type != "double"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
```

Comment: actually they do not to use any conditional operator